# все ли элементы списка похожи на первый

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while

```
listochek = ['Af', 'Af', 'Af']

i=0
while listochek[0] == listochek[i]:
    if i == len(listochek):
        i += 1
        print(len(listochek))
        print(i)
    else:
        break

if i == len(listochek):
    print("все одинаковое")
else:
    print("норм")
```

выводит:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    while listochek[0] == listochek[i]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `all(v == listochek[0] for v in listochek)`

Comment: Ну вы же не проверяете, что `i < len(listochek)`, у вас `i` может выйти за границы списка.

Answer (score 3):

```
listochek = ['Af', 'Af', 'Af']

if len(set(listochek)) == 1:
    print("все одинаковое")
else:
    print("норм")
```